# Why a selenium script runs successfully with Firefox webdriver, but not with PhantomJS webdriver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, phantomjs

I have written a selenium script in python which runs pretty successfully when I use `Firefox` webdriver. But, then I tried to make it headless, and so replaced `Firefox` with `PhantomJS` webdriver. But, same script doesn't run with `PhantomJS` webdriver.

It successfully logged in to the site, but fails to find most of the xpaths(those are dynamic contents) in the script, though the paths do exist,

For example:

```
def get_logged_in_session(redirect):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get("https://app.abcd.com/id?redirectTo=" + redirect)
    username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='Username']")
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='Password']")
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='login']")
    username.send_keys("")
    password.send_keys("")
    login_button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    return driver
```

This function runs successfully.

But then inside a particular account,

```
root_directory += driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@class='course-hero__title']").get_attribute("textContent")

names_of_directories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='accordian__section']")
```

This two runs successfully and fetch elements in `Firefox`, but raises exception/returns empty list in `PhantomJS`.

My question is, what is the change needed in my script to make it work with `PhantomJS`.

N.B. `PhantomJS-2.1.1` is successfully installed in my machine. And, I have provided enough delay so the page can be loaded fully. So, it is not a delay issue.

Comment: "*..but fails to find most of the xpaths in the script, **though the paths do exist***". How can you be sure that the elements exist in the same path in case of PhantomJS? Have you tried to save and inspect the HTML source using PhantomJS driver?

Comment: Actually, I am quite novice in html and js things, and my questions can be stupid, but *shouldn't it be the case, that PhantomJS and Firefox will load the same content from same page?* Why they would vary? I have no idea actually.

Comment: Some elements might be generated dynamically using javascript, some HTML source might be broken initially, which will cause browser to attempt to fix it: these processes done by different browser engine might then results in a different final HTML

Comment: @har07, It seems you are right, I have taken a screenshot in the except clause of the exception, but it shows that, the login page still exists, though username and password field is filled. What's the case here?

Comment: try to submit authentication form with `login_button.submit()` or `login_button.click()` instead of `login_button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`

Comment: @AhsanulHaque If this is a public IP can you share the URL?